# Real-valued functions whose level sets are hyperplanes?

Tags: real-analysis

Does the class of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that all of their level sets $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x)=c\}$ are hyperplanes have a special name?

In either case, could someone direct me to a characterization result?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that they have a special name, but they are all composites of some linear function $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ with some injective function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.

**Proof:** Take a function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ with hyperplanes as level sets. These planes must all be parallel as they are not intersecting, so they all have some normal vector $v$ in common. Define the linear function $f_0:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ by scalar product with $v$.

Define $f_1:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by
$$
f_1(x) = f(f_0^{-1}(x))
$$
This is well-defined as each level set of $f_0$ is also a level set of $f$, and therefore $f$ only takes one value on all of $f_0^{-1}(x)$.

This gives $f = f_1\circ f_0$.